# Set DateFormat in WPF Application

Tags: wpf

Below is the code that i am using to set the date format in my the application.But Overriding the Language property does not updating the Date Format instead it still showing US date format("MM/dd/yyyy") in Listbox having list of date object bound to it.My WPF application is using 4.5.2 .Net Framework.

```
var newCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();

// Set desired date format here
newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";

CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = newCulture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = newCulture;

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCulture;

FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
    typeof(FrameworkElement),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

Comment: did you set the thread culture of the new thread = main thread?

Comment: I am not creating any new thread.When i debug the code behind of WPF view and see all the Cultures updated in my code having "dd/MM/yyyy" .But when i see the this.Language.GetSpecificCulture() has the Dateformat of US.

Comment: where are the provided code being called? is it before window initialization?

Comment: It is called on  OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e). I want to maintain the Language Tag as US and the date format to UK since in the code i provided will update only dateformat and not languagetag which is my requirement. So it is not working while overriding Language in Framework Element because XMLLanguage.GetLanguage method always returns the US Language with US culture and US date format and not the date format i updated in the threads.